# Ant Design download loading spinner during api call

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make my button from the Ant design library show a spinner animation while making an api call.

Here's the button https://ant.design/components/button/ (it's the loading button)

Also, I've been trying to convert it to a functional component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from '../../AppContext';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { RetweetOutlined, GlobalOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import axios from 'axios';


const APICallButton = () => {
  const [context, setContext] = useContext(AppContext);
  const [loadings, setLoadings] = useState([]);


  const apiCall = () => {
    axios.get('api/endpoint')
    .then(res => {
                setContext(prev => ({...prev, state: res.data})))
                // Remove loading spinner?
              }
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }


  return (
  <Button
    id='update-prices-btn'
    type="primary"
    icon={<GlobalOutlined />}
    loading={loadings[1]}
    onClick={() => {
      setContext(prev => ({...prev, products: apiCall()}))
    }}
  >
      Make API Call
  </Button>
  )
}

export default APICallButton
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you fire the API call, set the loading state to true.
When your API call completes or fails, set the loading state to false.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const apiCall = () => {

    // Before you fire the API call, set the loading state to true.
    setLoading(true);

    axios.get('api/endpoint')
        .then(res => {
            setContext(prev => ({...prev, state: res.data})))

            // When your API call completes or fails, set the loading state to false.
            setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);

            // Also need to set loading to false if your request fails
            setLoading(false);
        });
}
```

Then use the `loading` state variable to control your components (eg. show a spinner).

```
<Button loading={loading} ... />
```